# Django No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Hey I tried find something what resolve my problem but nothing helped me. I'm trying to install 'psycopg2' to using PostreSQL in my project.

I tried install it using pip, easy_install ect. I'm using PyCharm so i tried install it i "install package window" but I'm getting something like this:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Bartek\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\psycopg2\
```

I'm working on Windows for now, can you give me some advice how resolve this problem? I'm sitting on it more than 2 hours :(

After install clean PostgreSQL i tried again "pip install psycopg2" and i got:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Bartek\dJangoEnvironment\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Bartek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Bartek\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2ohduth5pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\psycopg1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\dbapi20_tpc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\testconfig.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\testutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_async.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_bugX000.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_bug_gc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_cancel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_connection.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_copy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_cursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_dates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_green.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_lobject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_notify.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_quote.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_transaction.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_types_basic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_types_extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_with.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Bartek\dJangoEnvironment\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Bartek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Bartek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-si2d11i4-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Bartek\dJangoEnvironment\include\site\python3.5\psycopg2:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\psycopg1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\dbapi20_tpc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\testconfig.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\testutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_async.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_bugX000.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_bug_gc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_cancel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_connection.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_copy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_cursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_dates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_green.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_lobject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_notify.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_quote.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_transaction.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_types_basic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_types_extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_with.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Command "C:\Users\Bartek\dJangoEnvironment\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Bartek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Bartek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-si2d11i4-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Bartek\dJangoEnvironment\include\site\python3.5\psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Bartek\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\psycopg2\
```

Answer (score 2):

Install [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/), add `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\` to your path and try `pip install psycopg2` again.

Looks like you need to download [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-homepage-vs.aspx) as well.

Comment: Its better because installation started but i got next error Failed building wheel for psycopg2. I put all error log up ^

Comment: unfortunately it's the same error Failed building wheel for psycopg2

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio, as I suggested and then do pip install psycopg2. Or, as a pure python (no postgres/VS), use [pg8000](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000).

Answer (score 0):

**I resolve my problem using:**

http://samudranb.com/2012/06/02/how-to-setup-a-djangopython-development-env-on-windows/

This is only solution for me. Visual, PostgreSQL doesn't help for this.